# Change multiple rows and column values at the same time with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to change the values of 9 members of a 10x10 pandas dataframe, preferably at the same time. I have a 3x3 matrix of values, let's say:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> xx = np.array(range(1, 10)).reshape(3, 3)
>>> xx
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Now I have a 10x10 zeros Dataframe df:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(100).reshape(10, 10), index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], columns = ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y'])
>>> df
     p    q    r    s    t    u    v    w    x    y
a  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
b  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
d  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
e  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
f  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
g  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
h  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
i  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
j  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

I want to insert the 3x3 matrix xx at rows "b", "d" and "g", and at columns "t", "v", and "w", where these intersect, so that it looks like this afterwards:

```
     p    q    r    s    t    u    v    w    x    y
a  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
b  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  2.0  3.0  0.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
d  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0  5.0  6.0  0.0  0.0
e  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
f  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
g  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0  0.0  8.0  9.0  0.0  0.0
h  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
i  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
j  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Is this doable in a single step or a few efficient steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `update` method:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(100).reshape(10, 10), 
                  index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], 
                  columns = ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y'])

xx = np.array(range(1, 10)).reshape(3, 3)
xx = pd.DataFrame(xx, index=['b', 'd', 'g'], columns=['t','v','w'])

df.update(xx)
df
```

Output:

```py
      p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y
a   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
b   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 2.0 3.0 0.0 0.0
c   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
d   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 5.0 6.0 0.0 0.0
e   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
f   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
g   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 7.0 0.0 8.0 9.0 0.0 0.0
h   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
i   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
j   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

The documentation explains more in detail: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html